# php include_paths in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, include, filesystems, directory-structure

I have a few things in various different files that get called from different places. I've been trying to use a $ROOT variable, but because I'm going from a few different files (index.php, view.php, admin/index.php etc) and don't have a bootstrap(or whatever that's called), I can't always get to $ROOT from things called by ajax etc..

if I set the include_path via htaccess somewhat like:

`php_value include_path ".;C:\wamp\www\project\"`

I assume that doesn't include subdirectories, and I would also have to add a line for each other directory where my files reside even if they're in `C:\wamp\www\project\components` or `C:\wamp\www\project\model`?

And do I add new lines or commas? I can't find any example online of using the htaccess to set include paths with multiple paths...

Alternately is there a way to get everything relating to my $ROOT variable and use absolute paths, and somehow have every file, even if they're in different places, reference that particular variable? (without having to make wholesale changes to all the files in the app?)  That has the benefit of only needing to change on file in a server change/deployment, but I do not know how to start going about it!

thanks :)

Comment: You can change the include path dynamically from within a script, which'd let you use your $ROOT var. But then you run into a chicken-egg problem - if $ROOT is in a file that's not in your include path already, you can't include it without an absolute path.

Comment: Yeah.. that chicken and egg potential is something I'm trying to get around. It's been making my brain sad. I guess if i includepath the directory with the config, require_once config.php on the top of every page and then use my $root var everywhere else I should be covered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I assume that doesn't include subdirectories,

Why didn't you try it? (it does include sub dirs)

> I can't find any example online of using the htaccess to set include paths with multiple paths

? You've already provided one:

> php_value include_path ".;C:\wamp\www\project\"

The paths are '.' and 'C:\wamp\www\project\'

(BTW its better practice to use '/' as the dir seperator - it avoids confusion over unix style escaping)

Comment: p.s. the files weren't being included but i wasn't sure if it was the subdir thing or just that my htaccess file isn't working at all.. i guess it's the latter

Comment: @Damon: '.' is the current directory

Comment: current directory in relation to the htaccess file, not the php file? (the reason so much I read about this is confusing is that 'write the path' can be taken in many different ways..)

Comment: The current directory of the executing process - by default that's the directory where the base php script was started in (i.e. does not change for files included from other locations)

Comment: isn't that where it looks for files anyway? or does that get overridden by the htaccess if it's not explicitly specified?

Answer (score 0):

In a Windows environment, you would use semicolons to separate include paths like so:

```
php_value include_path ".;C:\wamp\www\project\;C:\wamp\www\project\components;C:\wamp\www\project\models"
```

But I'm not sure why you'd want to do so. Adding sub-directories opens up the possibility of file naming collisions. If you have, C:\wamp\www\project\components\example.php and C:\wamp\www\project\models\example.php, including both sub-directories in your include path will create ambiguity when you try to include either file. If you already have the project directory in your include path, you can already call anything inside it using a relative path. For instance:

```
<?php include 'components/example.php'; ?>
```

This would include C:\wamp\www\project\components\example.php and eliminate the chance of any file naming collisions.